# EBSレプリケートについて

Tags: aws

EBSの可用性については、同ゾーン内にレプリケートするため冗長化は不要との記載を目にします。
もし利用しているEBSに障害が発生した場合、レプリケートされたディスクからインスタンスを復旧することができるのでしょうか。
可能な場合、AWS内部で行われるのか、手動で実行する必要があるのかも知りたいです。

このようなことが可能なら、(ハード障害での)スナップショットの必要性があまり感じられないと思いまして。

Answer (score 2):

ポイントとして「可用性」と「耐久性」があります。
https://aws.amazon.com/jp/ebs/features/#durabilityandsecurity
こちらを確認すると

可用性について

> 99.999% の可用性を維持する設計となっています

耐久性について

> ボリュームのサイズやパフォーマンスに応じて年間故障率 (AFR) が 0.1%～0.2% になるように設計されています。この場合の「故障」は、ボリュームが完全に、または部分的に失われることを指します。

可用性については「停止なく動き続けるか」というもので
自動でレプリケーションが動くことで
「99.999%」であれば年間で365 * 24 * 60 * 60 *  0.00001 = 315.36秒の利用できない時間があることになります。

そして耐久性については「データが破損なく維持できるかというもので」
1000ボリューム運用していれば1個か2個は完全にもしくは部分的に失われます。

> 可能な場合、AWS内部で行われるのか、手動で実行する必要があるのかも知りたいです。

A.レプリケーションについては自動で行われますが、年間315秒は停止する可能性があります。
それ以上は自前で可用性を確保する必要があります。

> このようなことが可能なら、(ハード障害での)スナップショットの必要性があまり感じられないと思いまして。

A.1000個に1個か2個壊れるという割合を鑑みてスナップショットの必要性を確認してみてはどうでしょうか？
ちなみに壊れるとEBSのサポートから
「あなたのボリュームは根本的なハードウェア・コンポーネントの
多重故障により失敗を経験しました。また、私たちはそれを回復することができませんでした。」
というメッセージが届くことがあります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

耐久性については(年間故障率が 0.1%～0.2%)理解しました。
レプリケートされたものも含めて故障するのは少ないかもしれませんが、論理障害などを考慮するとスナップショットを取得したほうが良さそうですね。